# VBA syntax to exclude certain file types

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that will list all excel spreadsheets in a network folder but ignores any temporary files that excel creates while a spreadsheet is open (ie: ~$filename.xlsx) This code below works great however also picks up these temporary files.

```
If (objFile) Like ("*.xlsx") Then
            Do something here
        End If
        Next objFile
```

I've tried using an If Not statement but am having trouble getting it to work. I am new to VBA and it could be that my syntax is simply off. Is there a way to specify all .xlsx files while ignoring any temporary ~$*.xlsx files?

Comment: UPDATE: turns out some of the problem was cased by excel not seeing the "~" in the front of the temporary files. I was able to make a "filter" by excluding files that started with a *$ instead and that is working now.  Thank you everyone for answering!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just exclude strings starting with `~` in your `Like` statement:

```
If (objFile) Like ("[!~]*.xlsx") Then
    'Do something here
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is just to add an extra clause to the `If` statement:

```
    If objFile Like "*.xlsx" And Left(objFile, 2) <> "~$" Then
        Do something here
    End If
Next objFile
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using Dir- see code below:

```
Public Sub sampleCode()
Dim sourceFolderPath As String
Dim dirStr As String
Dim fileList As Collection

Set fileList = New Collection
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Select the folder that contains the pictures."
    .Show
    sourceFolderPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

dirStr = Dir(sourceFolderPath & "*.xlsx")
Do Until dirStr = ""
    fileList.Add (dirStr)
    dirStr = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

I stored the filenames in a collection but obviously you could store them in an array or whatever best suits your needs..

Regards,
TheSilkCode